# We cannot write any assignment statement globally why?

Tags: c, global-variables, variable-assignment

Why we cannot write any assignment statement globally ?My code is below

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  static int i=10;   //Initialization statement
  i=25;              //Assignment statement not possible why?
  int main()
{
 printf("%d",i);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: What makes you think you should be able to write arbitrary code that isn't in a function?

Answer (score 1):

It is a question of "when".

`int i=10;` is determined at compile time and the `i` takes on the value of `10` when the program is loaded or first begins to run.

A global `i=25;` has **no sequence**.  With multiple linked files, there is no control of the order in which these "global" codes should run - aside from maybe link order.

By moving `int i=10;` into `main()`, the order of evaluation is determined.

```
#include <stdio.h>
static int i=10;

int main(void) {
  printf("%d",i);
  i=25;
  printf("%d",i);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need a variable to exist outside the scope of all your functions, you can declare it globally, then your functions can modify as needed without needing to pass in the variable to the function.

What you are doing is declaring and then modifying, so why not declare it to the value you really want? If you need to change it, change the variable within a function as needed.

Although the global declarations are allowed, ask yourself why you can't declare locally and pass the variable to the functions. If you can't answer that question properly, you probably shouldn't use the variable that way. Note that maintaining a large program will become more difficult, the more you arbitrarily declare variables.

Answer (score 0):

C works differently to a (so called) scripting language, like Ruby or Perl.

Despite looking a lot like the code inside a function (between the curly brackets) the code outside functions is never actually run. It is used by the compiler to declare and define variables that can be accessed from the code that actually runs. The code that runs is defined inside the functions.

When the compiler compiles a program it produces executable code fragments for each of the functions then "links" then together to produce the final program. As execution doesn't start at the top of the file a place has to be defined for this; in C the compiler arranges for the function "main" to be called when you run the program.